# Embedding form on top of QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I need support on displaying the form (designed by using QT designer) on top of the QGIS window.

My concern is, after loading my plugin, my designed form is opening on top of the QGIS application window. If i click any other place on QGIS window, the opened UI window disappears and moves behind QGIS. I want to access UI window and QGIS canvas same time.

How can I design a UI like this?

Answer (score 3):

When you create a plugin with the plugin builder (its a plugin by itself and can be found in the Plugin menu) you can choose to create a new plugin as **dock widget** which is done in the 3. step of the plugin creation.

Here you choose the templet as *Tool button with dock widget* and define where it will be placed initially (see the image)

[image: Options of the lugin builder]

As a result, your form will be placed for example in the lower left corner below the layer planel